# Multiple linked sessions/instances of Vim and R with Vim-r-plugin

Tags: macos, r, vim, macvim

OSX 10.8. MacVim + Vim-r-plugin = Vim sends commands to R. Awesome! (Note I'm here asking about using MacVim and R.app (i.e. w/ Gui), not either in a terminal, since for this purpose I need both to have the usual application UI.)

But: can I launch multiple instances of MacVim, and multiple instances of the R app, and have them linked up correctly? \rf on a new (GUI-)window in MacVim (as in OSX window, not in-vim-window) does not launch a new R session but rather "finds" (and focuses) the existing one, even though the (GUI-)windows of MacVim are to some degree sandboxed (e.g. can't y/p across them). This remains true even when I force an actual new instance of MacVim using `open -n -a MacVim`. Opening new R instances that way just makes all sent commands (from any of the MacVim windows/instances) head to the newest instance of R.

Any clever solutions? Diagram showing what I want

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|    MacVim 1 <--> R 1    ||    MacVim 2  <--> R 2    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

etc.

Comment: There used to be an option called vimrplugin_by_vim_instance for exactly this. However, the changelog shows that this option was removed in version 0.9.9.2. Can't think why? Perhaps, you should email the author. His email is available if you'll do `:help vim-r-plugin` in command mode.

Comment: havbe you tried `:help vim-r-plugin` I am pretty sure it is described in the help !

Comment: All I could find was what @asb said; maybe I'm not looking hard enough or in the right places?